# For each row, output the column names of the top 5 columns with the highest values, but leave out 0

Tags: r, algorithm, function

My question is coded in R, so any help / solutions coded in R would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following matrix:

```
df <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.018, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.034, 0, 0.008, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 0, 0.004, 0, 
0.002, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 0, 0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0.054, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.004, 0, 0, 0.028, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.034, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 
0.012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.008, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0, 0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 0, 0.018, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.018, 0, 0.196, 0.012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.094, 
0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.014, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.034, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 0, 0.004, 0, 0.132, 
0, 0.002, 0.396, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.012, 0, 0, 0.004, 0, 
0.082, 0, 0, 0.038, 0, 0.014, 0, 0, 0, 0.006, 0.1, 0.006, 0.616, 
0.174, 0.12, 0, 0.12, 0.036, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.004, 0, 0, 0.036, 0, 0.042, 0, 
0.002, 0.058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0.874, 0.058, 0.874, 0.148, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 0.022, 0, 0, 
0.036), .Dim = c(5L, 100L), .Dimnames = list(c("4", "5", "8", 
"9", "14"), c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", 
"X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16", 
"X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", "X21", "X22", "X23", "X24", "X25", 
"X26", "X27", "X28", "X29", "X30", "X31", "X32", "X33", "X34", 
"X35", "X36", "X37", "X38", "X39", "X40", "X41", "X42", "X43", 
"X44", "X45", "X46", "X47", "X48", "X49", "X50", "X51", "X52", 
"X53", "X54", "X55", "X56", "X57", "X58", "X59", "X60", "X61", 
"X62", "X63", "X64", "X65", "X66", "X67", "X68", "X69", "X70", 
"X71", "X72", "X73", "X74", "X75", "X76", "X77", "X78", "X79", 
"X80", "X81", "X82", "X83", "X84", "X85", "X86", "X87", "X88", 
"X89", "X90", "X91", "X92", "X93", "X94", "X95", "X96", "X97", 
"X98", "X99")))
```

I want to output the column names of the columns with the top 5 values, and leave out 0s.

Currently, I have:

```
myfunction <- function(x, names) {
  ord <- order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]
  names[ord]
}

col <- colnames(df)
output <- apply(df, 1, myfunction, names = col)
output <- t(output)
```

But as you can see from output, it includes X0, X1...etc. whenever the next highest value is 0. How do I amend my code so that it extracts column names only for non-zero values, and when the next highest value is 0, it just leaves it blank and move on?

Thank you very much in advance for any tips and guidance!

EDIT:

The current output of `output` is:

```
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] 
4  "X91" "X65" "X64" "X0"  "X1" 
5  "X59" "X64" "X48" "X62" "X12"
8  "X91" "X65" "X64" "X0"  "X1" 
9  "X64" "X46" "X91" "X65" "X59"
14 "X59" "X64" "X91" "X82" "X62"
```

I want the output to be:

```
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] 
4  "X91" "X65" "X64" ""  "" 
5  "X59" "X64" "X48" "X62" "X12"
8  "X91" "X65" "X64" ""  "" 
9  "X64" "X46" "X91" "X65" "X59"
14 "X59" "X64" "X91" "X82" "X62"
```

because for 4 and 8, only the top 3 values are non-zero.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the rows of 'df', create an index for value that are not 0 ('i1'), subset the 'x' base on 'i1', `order` it decreasingly ('i1') to get the numeric index ('i2'), using that we extract the first 5 elements with `head`.  The output will be a `list` as some rows have less than 5 non-zero elements.  Loop through the `list`, assign the `length` to maximum of the `length` of `list` element to pad `NAs` at the end to keep the length equal, `rbind` the `list` elements, and if needed `replace` the NA with 0.

```
lst <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) {
        i1 <- x!=0
        i2 <- order(-x[i1])
        head(colnames(df)[i1][i2], 5)})
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
replace(res, is.na(res), "")
# [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] 
#4  "X91" "X65" "X64" ""    ""   
#5  "X59" "X64" "X48" "X62" "X12"
#8  "X91" "X65" "X64" ""    ""   
#9  "X64" "X46" "X91" "X65" "X59"
#14 "X59" "X64" "X91" "X82" "X62"
```